# Google Drive (for PC) halts syncing at <= 1GB free - can this minimum be configured?

Tags: google-drive

Using a virtual (encrypted) drive as the target for local sync.  I have selective sync enabled, only one folder selected, less than 1MB of files.

The virtual drive is 50 MB, but GD refuses to sync to it, claiming that "the computer has run out of disk space".  Research on the Product Help forums suggests Google has an undocumented 1GB minimum free space for whatever drive the local files are sync'd to (presumably because the default sync path is in the windows user folder and they don't want to be responsible for people inadvertently filling up their boot drives with cat photos).

Are there any hidden settings or workarounds to configure this minimum setting?  I could just make a much, much larger virtual drive than I need, but that's incredibly irritating - I'd rather solve the *actual* problem.

Comment: Since this is a question about the client app and _not_ about the web interface, this question is very much on-topic here at [su]. It is _off-topic_ at [webapps.se].